# How to impose orthonormality constraints by method of Lagrange multipliers

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, lagrange-multiplier, orthonormal

I want to find the matrix $\Phi: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$, $m<n$ that minimizes
$$V={\rm tr}(\Phi R \Phi^T)$$
subject to the orthonormality constraint
$$\Phi\Phi^T=I$$
where $R: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ is a given symmetric positive definite matrix.

How do I apply the Lagrange multiplier method to this constrained optimization problem?

**I tried:**
$$\tilde{V}={\rm tr}(\Phi R \Phi^T) - {\rm tr}\left(\Lambda(\Phi\Phi^T-I)\right)$$
where $\Lambda:\mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}^m$ is a general matrix of Lagrange multipliers, and this yields the necessary conditions for minimality:
$$\frac{\partial \tilde{V}}{\partial \Lambda}=\Phi\Phi^T-I=0$$
$$\frac{\partial \tilde{V}}{\partial \Phi}=R\Phi^T-\Phi^T\Lambda=0$$
The first equation is the orthonormality condition, so far so good. But how is the second equation supposed to find minimum candidates/critical points? Intuitively, I think I know that the global minimum argument $\Phi$ must be the basis of the eigenspace of the lowest $m$ eigenvalues of $R$. **But $\Lambda$ is a general $m\times m$ matrix and nothing seems to constrain it to a diagonal matrix with $m$ eigenvalues (let alone the lowest) on the diagonal**.

Or am I applying the Lagrange multiplier method the wrong way?

**By the way:** it seems easy for $m=1$. Then $\Phi^T$ simply becomes a vector and $\Lambda=\lambda$ becomes a scalar. This yields the eigenvalue problem for one eigenvector, which is 'diagonal' in the trivial sense:
$$R\Phi^T-\lambda\Phi^T=0$$

Comment: I presume the answer is the sum of the smallest $m$ eigenvalues of $R$?

Comment: Yeah, as far as I understand it, see my question. But that should follow from the equations, right?

Comment: If you multiply on the left the second equation by $\Phi$ you get $\Lambda=\Phi R \Phi^T$ knowing that $\Phi \Phi^T=I$.

Comment: @copper.hat: please notice the trace... you will probably see that it's correct if you compute the expressions in components

Comment: I deleted my comment, I misunderstood what you were doing.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net: exactly, but then this equation just says that $\Lambda$ is a general symmetric (and I think also positive definite) matrix. But in order to relate it to eigenvalues, $\Lambda$ would have to be diagonal. And I can't see that this follows from the equations.

Comment: I don't think using Lagrange is going to give you any more enlightment than say starting with a diagonal $R$.

Comment: @copper.hat: I don't understand what you mean by that. I have what I think is a well-posed problem: optimize $V$ subject to the orthonormality constraint. My guess is that the solution is kind of principal component analysis reversed (lowest eigenvalues instead of highest) and I can solve that. But what I would like to know is: why does Langrange's multiplier method not yield the expected result to the original problem uniquely, but leaves a lot of freedom in $\Lambda$. Either I misunderstand Lagrange multiplier method, or it does not work (joke).

Comment: To put it another way: the last paragraph of my question shows that Lagrange mutliplier method can find a one-dimensional eigenspace. Why can't it find a m>1 dimensional eigenspace?

Comment: One minor point, to apply Lagrange, the derivatives of the (scalar) equality constraints must be linearly independent. The orthornomality constraint corresponds to ${1 \over 2} m (m+1)$ scalar constraints. However, you can notice that $\operatorname{tr}(\Lambda (\Phi \Phi^T-I) ) = \operatorname{tr}({1 \over 2}(\Lambda + \Lambda^T)(\Phi \Phi^T-I) )$ so you can presume that $\Lambda$ is symmetric to begin with.

Comment: @copper.hat: I noticed that, but then I would have to decompose $\Lambda$ in a symmetric matrix basis, in order to be able to derive the objective function with respect to $\Lambda$, right? Thus, I deemed it easier to let the symmetry turn out 'automatically'.

Comment: Basically yes, but in this case it would end up with the same result except that $\Lambda$ would be automatically symmetric. Which I think it about all the Lagrange multipliers let you conclude here.

Comment: Wildly vague & loose comment here, but very generally I find that Lagrange multipliers are good for revealing symmetry, structure or geometric sorts of things. It is not a real surprise as the result is a geometric one. But often not much more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Lagrange multiplier method does put a special constraint on the structure of $\Lambda$, but that isn't what you expected.

From $\Phi\Phi^T=I$ and $R\Phi^T=\Phi^T\Lambda$, we obtain $\Lambda=\Phi\Phi^T\Lambda=\Phi R\Phi^T$. The constraint placed on the structure of $\Lambda$ is *not* that $\Lambda$ must be diagonal, but that $\Lambda$ must be symmetric.

Since $\Lambda$ is symmetric, it can be orthogonally diagonalised as $QDQ^T$. Therefore, $R\Phi^T=\Phi^T\Lambda$ implies that $R(\Phi^TQ)=(\Phi^TQ)D$. The eigenvectors of $R$ are the columns of $\Phi^TQ$ rather than the columns of $\Phi^T$.

This makes sense if you look at the original objective function. Since $\Phi R\Phi^T$ has the same trace as $(Q^T\Phi) R(\Phi^TQ)$ for every $Q\in SO(m)$, there is no reason why the columns of any $\Phi^T$ that minimises $\operatorname{tr}(\Phi R\Phi^T)$ must be eigenvectors of $R$.

Comment: +1: Nice explanation.

Comment: Thanks, that explains most part of the problem. But is there a way to impose an additional constraint on $\Lambda$ that forces the solution to turn out diagonal and hence, remove what I might call the 'gauge symmetry' of the objective function $\tilde{V}$ under $Q$? Of course then, there is still the ambiguity regarding which choice of eigenvalues enters $\Lambda$, but that is also present in the one-dimensional subspace eigenvalue equation.

Comment: @oliver I think both of the answers are hinting at the fact that if you use the "gauge symmetry to make $\Lambda$ diagonal you trivialize the structure of $R\Phi^T=\Phi^T\Lambda$, but you're not finding $\Lambda$ itself, you are finding it's diagonal part..That's the trick I use below to solve the system. Extracting the full $\Lambda$ matrix is hard, and I think it is obvious to see that the system cannot be trivialized. The only way this can turn into the subspace eigenvalue eqns you are thinking abt is if you hardwire that the rows of $\Phi$ are orthogonal to each other.

Comment: Errata - your second paragraph should begin "From $\Phi\Phi^T=I\,\ldots\;$

Comment: @oliver This is not different from other constrained optimisation problems. The first-order conditions can only give you potential extrema. They don't force the solution to be a real minimum.

Comment: @user1551: haven't you just shown that the invariance of $V$ under the left-sided transform under $Q^T$ is reponsible for the ambiguity "diagonal vs. just symmetric" $\Lambda$? The first-order conditions are just responsible for the ambiguity about which specific eigenvalues are selected by a specific $\Lambda$. You can see this very easily for the single eigenvalue equation (last paragraph of my question): the necessary conditions only say that it's an eigenvalue, not if it's the largest (maximum), or the smallest (minimum) or any other eigenvalue (saddle point). If I ain't wrong, that is...

Answer (score 2):

It is impossible to achieve the diagonalization of $\Lambda$ as you wish to do.

Simply, the relation $\Phi\Phi^T=1$ imposes in total $\frac{m(m+1)}{2}$ constraints. Therefore one needs to use exactly the same amount of independent Lagrange multipliers to impose all these constraints on the minimization functional. The minimal choice of a multiplier matrix is the one presented above, where $\Lambda$ is a $m\times m$ symmetric matrix. Notice that this matrix contains exactly $\frac{m(m+1)}{2}$ independent Lagrange multipliers. If one was permitted to diagonalize this matrix, that would imply that there would only be $m$ independent constraints to impose, and that the expression for $\Lambda$ would be redundant, and hence subject to transformation to one with fewer degrees of freedom.

$\textbf{Example:}$

Let's attack the simplest case that is non-trivial, $m=2$. Then express $\Phi$ as follows:

$$\Phi=\begin{pmatrix}
\mathbf{q}_1\\\mathbf{q}_2
\end{pmatrix}~~,~~\Lambda=\begin{pmatrix}
\lambda_1&\lambda_3\\ \lambda_3&\lambda_2
\end{pmatrix}$$

where $q$'s are horizontal line vectors

$$\mathbf{q}_a=(q_{a1}, q_{a2},..., q_{an})$$

With this notation in place, and dropping the boldface notation for vectors henceforth, we can show that the minimization functional reduces for $m=2$ to the following:

$$V=q_1^TRq_1+q_2^TRq_2-\lambda_1(q_1^Tq_1-1)-\lambda_2(q_2^Tq_2-1)-2\lambda_3 q_1^Tq_2$$

and minimizing with respect to the vectors $\mathbf{q}$ we obtain the equations:

$$(R-\lambda_1I)q_1=\lambda_3 q_2\\
(R-\lambda_2I)q_2=\lambda_3 q_1\\$$

Eliminating $q_2$ from the equations we find that $q_1$ satisfies the following nonlinear eigenvalue problem:

$$[R^2-(\lambda_1+\lambda_2)R+(\lambda_1\lambda_2-\lambda_3^2)]q_1=0$$

We get lucky however, because this problem is factorizable into the form

$$(R-r_1(\lambda))(R-r_2(\lambda))q_1=0~\\r_1+r_2=\lambda_1+\lambda_2~,~r_1r_2=\lambda_1\lambda_2-\lambda_3^2$$
which basically an eigenvalue problem. We denote the set of eigenvalues of $R$ as $E_R=\{\omega_1,..., \omega_n\}$ and the set of normalized eigenvectors $V_R=\{e_{1R},...,e_{nR}\}$. It is easy to show that $r_1, r_2 \in E_R$, and therefore the set of solutions to the above equation is discrete: $$(r_1,r_2)=(\omega_i,\omega_j), j\geq i$$

Note that there exist exactly $\frac{m(m+1)}{2}$ different solutions and not $m^2$ due to the symmetry $r_1\to r_2$. Now the question is, can we pin down the values of the Lagrange multipliers using these equations? The answer is positive, at least in principle.

Choose one of the solutions by fixing $r_1=\omega_i, r_2=\omega_j$ for some, appropriately chosen $i,j$. The general solution to the factorized eigenvalue problem is:

$$q_1=Ae_{iR}+Be_{jR}\\
q_2=\frac{A(\omega_i-\lambda_1)}{\lambda_3}e_{iR}+\frac{B(\omega_j-\lambda_1)}{\lambda_3}e_{jR}$$

where $A,B$ are arbitrary real parameters. We wish to solve for the matrices $\Lambda, \Phi$ but we only have partial information on them so far. It turns out we can write down exactly as many equations as necessary to determine all of their elements. We just need to apply the 3 constraints and the fact that the $\Lambda$ matrix is related to eigenvalues as follows:

$$\begin{align}
&\lambda_1+\lambda_2=\omega_{i}+\omega_{j}\\
&\lambda_1\lambda_2-\lambda^2_3=\omega_i\omega_j
\\& q_1^Tq_1=A^2+B^2=1
 \\&q_2^Tq_2=A^2(\frac{\omega_i-\lambda_1}{\lambda_3})^2+B^2(\frac{\omega_j-\lambda_1}{\lambda_3})^2=1
\\&q_2^Tq_1=A^2(\frac{\omega_i-\lambda_1}{\lambda_3})+B^2(\frac{\omega_j-\lambda_1}{\lambda_3})=0
\end{align}$$

These are five equations for five unknowns $A,B,\lambda_1,\lambda_2, \lambda_3$ and therefore they can in principle be solved.

$\textbf{Generalization:}$

These equations are highly nonlinear for general $m$  and it is not clear for general even whether a solution exists or not, because the vectors are supposed to be real. In a complex vector space where orthonormal matrices are replaced by Hermitian matrices, it's easier to guarantee that the problem has a solution. However, for general values of $m$ the problem can still be reduced to an eigenvalue problem. Consider the Cayley-Hamilton polynomial of the matrix $\Lambda$, defined by $P_{\Lambda}(x)=\det(\Lambda-xI)$. It may be written in the form:

$$P_{\Lambda}(x)=x^m-\text{tr}(\Lambda)x^{m-1}+\frac{\text{tr}(\Lambda^2)-\text{tr}(\Lambda)^2}{2}x^{m-2}+...+(-1)^m \det(\Lambda)$$

It may be shown that the vectors $\mathbf{q}_1,...,\mathbf{q}_m$ all satisfy the equation

$$P_{\Lambda}(R)\mathbf{q_i}=0~~,~~ i={1,...,m}$$

which can be subsequently factorized and solved for $q_1$ at least:

$$q_1=\sum_{a=1}^{m-1} A_a e_{i_a R}~,~ i_a\geq i_{a+1}~,~ i_a\in \{1,..n\}$$

The other vectors can be determined from $q_1$. One can also see easily that the factorization provides $m-1$ constraints and the total constraints are $\frac{m(m+3)}{2}-1$. These are exactly enough of them to determine the coefficients of each eigenvector attached to each possible eigenvalue combination and the Lagrange multipliers, as illustrated in the $m=2$ example.