# derivative of quadratic form with respect to orthogonal matrix for optimization of quadratic form

Tags: matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus, quadratic-forms

I have the quadratic form:

$$
f(P;Y,\Lambda) = Y^\top P\Lambda P^\top Y,
$$

where $\Lambda$ is a diagonal $p\times p$ matrix of real (positive) values, $P$ is an real orthogonal matrix, and $Y$ is a $p$-dimensional vector of reals. I want to find the  derivative of $f(P;Y,\Lambda)$ with regard to the orthogonal matrix $P$. In general, I know how to do this for a symmetric (non-singular) matrix, but how do I do this if $P$ is orthogonal?

If I have a general case, if I am finding the P optimizing $f(P;Y,\Lambda)$, then I understand from the solution offered that I can use Lagrange multipliers? However, I am a little cofused how to go about this then, since then I have to take the derivative of:
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial P} f(P;Y,\Lambda) + \gamma\frac{\partial}{\partial P} (PP^\top-I) +\delta \frac{\partial}{\partial P} (P^\top P-I)
$$
subject to $PP^\top=P^\top P=I$. Is there a more direct way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$
\def\bbR#1{{\mathbb R}^{#1}}
\def\l{\Lambda}\def\o{{\tt1}}\def\p{\partial}
\def\L{\left}\def\R{\right}
\def\LR#1{\L(#1\R)}
\def\BR#1{\Big(#1\Big)}
\def\bR#1{\big(#1\big)}
\def\skew#1{\operatorname{skew}\LR{#1}}
\def\cayley#1{\operatorname{cayley}\LR{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\operatorname{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
$Use an *unconstrained* matrix variable $U$ to construct the orthogonal matrix $P$ as follows
$$\eqalign{
S &= \skew{U} \;\;\;\doteq\; \tfrac 12\LR{U-U^T} &\qiq S^T=-S \\
P &= \cayley{S} \;\doteq\;  \LR{I+S}^{-1}\LR{I-S} &\qiq P^TP=I \\
dP &= -\LR{I+S}^{-1}dS\LR{I+P} &\qiq dS=\skew{dU} \\
}$$
Then use Golden_Ratio's gradient (with respect to $P$) to write the differential of the function, perform a change of variables from $dP\to dU,\,$ and recover the unconstrained gradient
$$\eqalign{
df &= 2\LR{yy^TP\l}:dP \\
 &= -2\LR{yy^TP\l}:\LR{\LR{I+S}^{-1}dS\LR{I+P}} \\
 &= -2\LR{\LR{I-S}^{-1}\LR{yy^TP\l}\LR{I+P^T}}: {dS} \\
 &= -2\LR{\LR{I-S}^{-1}\LR{yy^TP\l}\LR{I+P^T}}: \skew{dU} \\
 &= -2\skew{\LR{I-S}^{-1}\LR{yy^TP\l}\LR{I+P^T}}:dU \\
\grad{f}{U}
 &= -2\skew{\LR{I-S}^{-1}\LR{yy^TP\l}\LR{I+P^T}}
 \;\;\doteq\;\; G \\
}$$
Now $G$ can be used  in your favorite unconstrained gradient-based algorithm to find the optimal $U_*$ after which it is trivial to calculate the corresponding optimal matrices
$$\eqalign{
S_* &= \skew{U_*} \qiq
P_* &= \LR{I+S_*}^{-1}\LR{I-S_*} \\\\
}$$

---

In the steps above, a colon is used to denote the Frobenius product, which is a concise notation for the trace
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}B_{ij} \;=\; \trace{A^TB} \\
A:A &= \big\|A\big\|^2_F \\
}$$
The properties of the underlying trace function allow the terms in such a product to be rearranged in many different but equivalent ways, e.g.
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= B:A \\
A:B &= A^T:B^T \\
C:\LR{AB} &= \LR{CB^T}:A = \LR{A^TC}:B \\
A:\skew{B} &= \skew{A}:B \\
}$$

Comment: My apologies, but the update confuses me. How do I go from here to get the optimal P?

Comment: @user3236841  I removed the confusing update. Just use a gradient-based method (like conjugate gradients or barzilai-borwein) to solve for the optimal $U$ using iterations like $$U_{k+1} = U_k - \lambda_k G_k$$ where $\lambda_k$ is the step length in the direction of the gradient $G_k\;$

Comment: Thanks! Can you please add this in the answer, and then it will be easy for posterity to read instead of having to go through the comments.

Answer (score 2):

You are differentiating a scalar by a $p\times p$ matrix so the result will be a $p\times p$ matrix. [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus#Scalar-by-matrix_identities) tells us

$$\partial_X\text{tr}(AXBX'C)=B'X'A'C'+BX'CA.$$

The above is more general than in your case (in your case, the trace operation can be dropped), but applying it gives

$$\partial_P Y'P\Lambda P'Y= 2\Lambda P'YY'.$$

Depending on your convention, either this or its transpose is your answer.

Comment: Thank you, so the fact that P is orthogonal does not play any role in the solution?

Comment: @user3236841 $P$ is arbitrary in taking the derivative. If you intend orthogonality to be a constraint in a constrained optimization, then see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3579028/how-to-impose-orthonormality-constraints-by-method-of-lagrange-multipliers

Comment: or see OPTIMIZATION PROBLEMS WITH
ORTHOGONAL MATRIX CONSTRAINTS (Arasu, Mohan)

Comment: thanks for the two references, the second one is extremely difficult to get from the library. I intend working these out and then adding to my question, but the first one is helpful, therefore.